# PHP regex add space between tags and text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have some inline contents such as:

```
<p>"Geen nuwe inisiatief, bestuur verandering, of verkryging in<a href="http://business.time.com/2013/09/24/the-fatal-mistake-that-doomed-blackberry/">2007 kon gered het die BlackBerry</a>. Dit was te laat, en die kloof is te groot, "Arment geskryf.</p>
```

I would like to add a space in front of a tag and other tags (strong, italic, etc...) only if the tag is right next to a letter (can be a japanese sign too) and also add a space after the tag only if the character after is a letter too and not punctuation such as ., !, ?...

Do you have an idea on how I could achieve that?

My regex so far is:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)>(.*)<\/a>?/', ' $0', $out);
```

So obviously there is no condition...Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: lookahead assertions maybe, cant recall the syntax though.. this might help http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

`\s?<(a|strong|italic)(?=[\s>])(?:[^>=]|=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"\s]*))*\s?\/?>.*?<\/\1>(?=[\s,.;?!]|(?=.*?(\s)))`

**Replace With:** `_$0$2`  note this is a Space, followed by `$0` and a `$2`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- match an optional leading space before the tag, if there is a space, then this will automatically be replaced, if there is not a space one will be inserted
- only insert a space at the end if there is not already one there and only if the next character is not a punctuation mark.

There will be a problem with the last tag on the page if there are not more additional spaces on the page.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/bR2gZ3/1

**Sample text**

```
<p>"Geen nuwe inisiatief, bestuur verandering, of verkryging in<a href="http://business.time.com/2013/09/24/the-fatal-mistake-that-doomed-blackberry/">2007 kon gered het die BlackBerry</a>. Dit was te laat, <a href=Droid.jpg onmouseover=' var s=" <a href=NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.jpg </a> "; ' >Not the Droid you are looking for</a>en die kloof is te groot, "Arment geskryf.</p>
```

**After Replacement**

```
<p>"Geen nuwe inisiatief, bestuur verandering, of verkryging in <a href="http://business.time.com/2013/09/24/the-fatal-mistake-that-doomed-blackberry/">2007 kon gered het die BlackBerry</a>. Dit was te laat,  <a href=Droid.jpg onmouseover=' var s=" <a href=NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.jpg </a> "; ' >Not the Droid you are looking for</a> en die kloof is te groot, "Arment geskryf.</p>
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    a                        'a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    strong                   'strong'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    italic                   'italic'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s>]                    any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                               whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s,.;?!]                  any character of: a space, ',', '.', ';', '?',
                             '!'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```